# JDO Persist an existing entity creats new entry in DB

Tags: merge, jdo, persist

This is my too first exemple using JDO
I have the class Account :

```
public class Compte
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.INCREMENT)
    private int idCompte;
    // other attributes
    private Regle regle;
    // ....
}
```

I have entities saved in the table regle, and when i want to create a new Compte i retreive
one of those Regle and i add it to the new Compte and i make Compte persisted.
I do that :

```
Compte compte = new Compte();
Regle regle = retreiveRegleByName(name);
compte.setRegle(regle);
saveCompte(compte);

// this is the code of the method saveCompte()
public void creerCompteParticulier(CompteParticulier compteParticulier)
{
    // Persistence of a particular client account
    PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try
    {
        // begin transaction
        tx.begin();
        pm.makePersistent(compteParticulier);
        tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception exp)
    {

        LOGGER.error("Error: ", exp);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (tx.isActive())
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        pm.close();
    }        
}
```

The new Compte is added to the specific table but my problem is :
I have a new entity in the table regle.

Can you help me please, i'd like to create a new Compte with the Regle retreived from database and not a new Regle.

NB : dosn't exist a merge() method in JDO like in JPA ?
I think in jpa this problem is resolved by using merg().

Comment: What is the value of `compteParticulier.idCompte`? Is it by any chance 0?

Comment: Yes idCompte = 0 because Compte it's a new instance
But the idRegle is not zoro (not null) since i retreived it from DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`makePersistent` does "merging" of existing objects *when the object is an existing detached object*. Your object is clearly not detached, so suggest that you read up on detaching an object. Reading the log would have given plenty of insight

Comment: I read [there](http://db.apache.org/jdo/attach_detach.html) that the method pm.makePersistent() reattach the object. So why it creates a new Regle objet ?

Comment: it creates a new object because it isn't DETACHED. You can't reattach something that hasn't been detached in the first place.

Comment: I did this
    Regle regle = (Regle)pm.detachCopy(retreivedRegle);
    newCompte.setRegle(regle);
    pm.makePersistent(newCompte);

But i have always the same problem, it creates a new Regle instance

Comment: and the class is detachable is it ? Perhaps it isn't,. Clearly the log would tell you what is happening but I see no reference to it.

Comment: I added this annotation to the declaration of the entity 
    detachable="true"
and now it works well.
Thank you very much my too last question is :
how can i activate the log to display the log of the db oprations.
In the datanucleus.log i find only the enhacer's log.

Comment: read the docs perhaps ? try this one http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/logging.html