# JDO Many to One relationship inserting new record in second table

Tags: java, mysql, jdo, datanucleus

I have a many to one relationship in JDO where a table BAR is prepopulated with values:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class BAR {
    @PrimaryKey 
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Persistent
    @Unique
    private String name;   
}
```

I now want to insert into the database many new objects FOO that have a field and contraint to the BAR.id - so I don't want to add new records in the BAR table,I just want to insert into FOO with the relationship to the existing record in FOO.

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class FOO {
    @PrimaryKey @Expose
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Persistent @Expose
    BAR bar;
}
```

When I create my object and attempt to persist it, I get:

```
javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Insert of object "com.ba.orm.BAR@3bc8657a" using statement "INSERT INTO `BAR` (`NAME`) VALUES (?)" failed : Duplicate entry
```

Obvious what's going on, it's attempting to insert the child with the parent and failing at the database level - i can't figure out how to tell JDO that this is an existing record.  I'm just using DataNucleus and JDO 3 - not GAE.

This persistence code works, but I want to know if I can make my FOO object persist and create the releationship to the BAR table without having to fetch an attached copy of the BAR object and reset it with the setter.

This process of doing getObjectById and setting the object feels wrong to me and I feel like i'm missing something.  As the app grows, this is going to get more and more cumbersome.

```
 Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();

 tx.begin();

 BAR bar = pm.getObjectById(BAR.class, foo.getBar().getId());

 foo.setBar(bar);

 pm.makePersistent(foo);

 tx.commit();
```

Comment: An "existing record" is one just obtained via getObjectById (on the same PM) or is in detached state. Just as the JDO spec says

Comment: did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069733/jdo-persist-an-existing-entity-creats-new-entry-in-db?

Comment: Thanks Billy and user - yes i understand. Does this mean i'd have to go through and attach the object before persisting? Querying the database for BAR, pm.getObjectById(oldbar.id) to get an attached copy of BAR? - this works, but I was hoping there was a way to annotate my class so JDO knows it shouldn't try and merge.

Comment: why not present your persistence code that you are trying? then there is something to base comments on

Comment: updated with my transaction.  Trying to figure out a way to not have to replace the complete child field with an attached copy.

Comment: No idea what "feels wrong" means. You have 2 options, pull back a managed Bar, or have a detached Bar. What other option is there? and what "feels right"?